# Import WordNet In NLTK

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk, wordnet, stemming

I want to import *`wordnet`* dictionary but when i import Dictionary form *`wordnet`* i see this error :

```
 for l in open(WNSEARCHDIR+'/lexnames').readlines():
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Program Files\\WordNet\\2.0\\dict/lexnames'
```

I install wordnet2.1 in this directory but i cant import 
please help me to solve this problem

```
import nltk
from nltk import *
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from wordnet import Dictionary

print '-----------------------------------------'
print Dictionary.length
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
>>> nltk.download()
# Download window opens, fetch wordnet
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
```

Now I've a `WordNetCorpusReader` called `wn`. I don't know why you're looking for a `Dictionary` class, since there's no such class listed in the [docs](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.WordNetCorpusReader-class.html). The NLTK book, in [section 2.5](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch02.html#wordnet_index_term), explains what you can do with the `nltk.corpus.wordnet` module.

Comment: The version from @alvas worked for me using Jupyter notebook, python 3.5. `ntlk.download()` alone cannot open a GUI from inside a notebook. It sure would be nice if the help for this command did a better job of listing the correct strings to use for all the options.

Comment: Maybe there has been an update, but calling `ntlk.download()` in Jupyter opens the GUI on my Win10 computer. (Jupyter is running on localhost, and not on a remote host.)

Comment: Solved my problem.

Answer (score 9):

You should try these commands:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet')
```

It worked for me.