# Resource 'corpora/wordnet' not found on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, nltk, wordnet

I'm trying to get NLTK and wordnet working on Heroku. I've already done

```
heroku run python
nltk.download()
  wordnet
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But I get this error:

```
Resource 'corpora/wordnet' not found.  Please use the NLTK
  Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - '/app/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
```

Yet, I've looked at in /app/nltk_data and it's there, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-nltk

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I just had this same problem. What ended up working for me is creating an 'nltk_data' directory in the application's folder itself, downloading the corpus to that directory and adding a line to my code that lets the nltk know to look in that directory. You can do this all locally and then push the changes to Heroku.

So, supposing my python application is in a directory called "myapp/"

**Step 1: Create the directory**

```
cd myapp/
mkdir nltk_data
```

**Step 2: Download Corpus to New Directory**

```
python -m nltk.downloader
```

This'll pop up the `nltk` downloader. Set your *Download Directory* to `whatever_the_absolute_path_to_myapp_is/nltk_data/`. If you're using the GUI downloader, the download directory is set through a text field on the bottom of the UI. If you're using the command line one, you set it in the config menu.

Once the downloader knows to point to your newly created `nltk_data` directory, download your corpus.

Or in one step from Python code:

```
nltk.download("wordnet", "whatever_the_absolute_path_to_myapp_is/nltk_data/")
```

**Step 3: Let nltk Know Where to Look**

`ntlk` looks for data,resources,etc. in the locations specified in the `nltk.data.path` variable. All you need to do is add `nltk.data.path.append('./nltk_data/')` to the python file actually using nltk, and it will look for corpora, tokenizers, and such in there in addition to the default paths.

**Step 4: Send it to Heroku**

```
git add nltk_data/
git commit -m 'super useful commit message'
git push heroku master
```

That should work! It did for me anyway. One thing worth noting is that the path from the python file executing nltk stuff to the nltk_data directory may be different depending on how you've structured your application, so just account for that when you do `nltk.data.path.append('path_to_nltk_data')`

Comment: If you want to install NLTK data on Heroku without adding it to your git repo, see my solution below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37558445/387337

Comment: The key for me was to add nltk.data.path.append('./nltk_data/'). 

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

#### Update

[As Kenneth Reitz pointed out](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/steps/hooks/post_compile), a much simpler solution has been added to the heroku-python-buildpack.  Add a `nltk.txt` file to your root directory and list your corpora inside.  See [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-nltk](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/install.html) for details.

---

#### Original Answer

Here's a cleaner solution that allows you to install the NLTK data directly on Heroku without adding it to your git repo.

I used similar steps to install [Textblob](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/install.html) on Heroku, which uses NLTK as a dependency. I've made some minor adjustments to my original code in steps 3 and 4 that should work for an NLTK only installation.

The default heroku buildpack includes a [`post_compile` step](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/steps/hooks/post_compile) that runs after all of the default build steps have been completed:

```
# post_compile
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -f bin/post_compile ]; then
    echo "-----> Running post-compile hook"
    chmod +x bin/post_compile
    sub-env bin/post_compile
fi
```

As you can see, it looks in your project directory for your own `post_compile` file in the `bin` directory, and it runs it if it exists.  You can use this hook to install the nltk data.

1. Create the `bin` directory in the root of your local project.
2. Add your own `post_compile` file to the `bin` directory.

   ```
   # bin/post_compile
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   if [ -f bin/install_nltk_data ]; then
       echo "-----> Running install_nltk_data"
       chmod +x bin/install_nltk_data
       bin/install_nltk_data
   fi

   echo "-----> Post-compile done"
   ```
3. Add your own `install_nltk_data` file to the `bin` directory.

   ```
   # bin/install_nltk_data
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   source $BIN_DIR/utils

   echo "-----> Starting nltk data installation"

   # Assumes NLTK_DATA environment variable is already set
   # $ heroku config:set NLTK_DATA='/app/nltk_data'

   # Install the nltk data
   # NOTE: The following command installs the wordnet corpora, 
   # so you may want to change for your specific needs.  
   # See http://www.nltk.org/data.html
   python -m nltk.downloader wordnet

   # If using Textblob, use this instead:
   # python -m textblob.download_corpora lite

   # Open the NLTK_DATA directory
   cd ${NLTK_DATA}

   # Delete all of the zip files
   find . -name "*.zip" -type f -delete

   echo "-----> Finished nltk data installation"
   ```
4. Add `nltk` to your `requirements.txt` file (Or `textblob` if you are using Textblob).
5. Commit all of these changes to your repo.
6. Set the NLTK_DATA environment variable on your heroku app.

   ```
   $ heroku config:set NLTK_DATA='/app/nltk_data'
   ```
7. Deploy to Heroku.  You will see the `post_compile` step trigger at the end of the deployment, followed by the nltk download.

I hope you found this helpful!  Enjoy!

Comment: As is, the solution load nltk_data each time you deploy your application, which can be long. Is it necessary?

Comment: In my experience, the extra deploy time is negligible if you only install the nltk data you need.  For this specific question, installing wordnet every deploy would be extremely fast.  It's still efficient even if you need a handful of data packages.  Just don't try to install all of the nltk data and you should be fine for most use cases.

Comment: Awesome .. plus 1 for suggesting buildpacks : ) I really wonder why this doesn't have good votes yet!!

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeMoissinac you can easily keep a condition which checks if nltk is already installed or not. And install only if it's not.

Comment: Great answers! I have been looking for solutions for a long time and this is the best one so far.

Answer (score 5):

For Mac OS user only.

`python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data wordnet`

the corpora data can't be downloaded directly to the `/usr/share/nltk_data` folder. error reports "no permission", two solutions:

1. Add additional permission change to the Mac system, details refer to [Operation Not Permitted when on root El capitan (rootless disabled)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled) . However, I don't want to change to mac default setting just for this corpora. and I go for the second solution.
2. - Download the corpora to any directory you have the access to. `python -m nltk.downloader -d some_user_accessable_directory wordnet'. Noted, there you only download the required corpora, e.g., wordnet, reuters instead of the whole corpora from nltk.
   - Add path to nltk path. In py file, add following lines:

     `import nltk
     nltk.data.path.append('nltk_data')`

Comment: `python -m nltk.downloader -d C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data wordnet`  works for windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this issue. For those who are not working in virtual environment, will need to download to following directory in ubuntu:

```
/usr/share/nltk_data/corpora/wordnet
```

Instead of wordnet it could be brown or whatever.
You can directly run this command in your terminal if you want to download the corpus.

```
$ sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data wordnet
```

Again instead of wordnet it could be brown.

Answer (score 2):

This one works:

For Mac OS users.

```
python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/local/share/nltk_data wordnet
```

Answer (score 1):

Heroku now officially supports NLTK data, built-in!

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-nltk

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but since the "right" answer has changed thanks to Heroku offering support for `nltk`, I thought it might be worthwhile to answer.

Heroku now supports `nltk`. If you need to download something for `nltk` (wordnet in this example, or perhaps stopwords or a corpora), you can do so by simply including an `nltk.txt` file in the same root directory where you have your `Procfile` and `requirements.txt`. In your `nltk.txt` file you list each item you would like to download. For a project I just deployed I needed stopwords and wordnet, so my `nltk.txt` looks like this:

```
stopwords

wordnet
```

Pretty straightforward. And, of course, make sure you have the appropriate version of `nltk` specified in your `Pipfile` or `requirements.txt`. For the ground truth, visit https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-nltk.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same **problem** and I tried this solution and it is works. I just did put these:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet')
```

in the above code and it is run without problem.
so try it maybe help you.

Answer (score 1):

in my case after running

```
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet')
```

it did not work. The issue was wordnet.zip was unabale to unzip in its own so simple go to folder where`python3 -m textblob.download_corpora` this command installed package and unzip folder

```
cd ~
cd nltk_data/corpora/
unzip wordnet.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem while deploying a chatbot on Heroku platform. Although the answer from follyroof is a fool-proof solution, but in many cases, the size of the repository would be increased drastically.

So, I used the nltk.download('PACKAGE') in my app.py file. This way whenever app.py is run, the dependencies are automatically downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. This workaround by *Fred Foo* helped me to fix the issue
The following works for me:

```
# 1) execute the below written code 
# 2) a NLTK Download window will open
# 3) select "Corpora" tab and scroll down until "wordnet"
# 4) doubleclick to install

nltk.download()
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
```

[Import WordNet In NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661108/import-wordnet-in-nltk)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the issue when i tried to use this code lemmatizer.lemmatize('goes'), its actually because of packages they have not downloaded.
so try to download them using following code, may be it can solve many problems regarding to these,

nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('omw-1.4')

Thank You..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

On Mac:

I still needed to download the `omw-1.4` data. The code was running from an Python file and the `nltk_data/` directory is in the same directory like the Python file.

`nltk.download('wordnet', "nltk_data/")`

`nltk.download('omw-1.4', "nltk_data/")`

`nltk.data.path.append('nltk_data/')`

Answer (score 0):

** This answer does not belong to me. I found it somewhere on the internet**
unzip the wordnet.zip file manually using following code
!unzip /usr/share/nltk_data/corpora/wordnet.zip -d /usr/share/nltk_data/corpora/

You may check these notebook for reference :-
https://www.kaggle.com/code/shivanimalhotra91/nlp-using-glove-embeddings
or https://www.kaggle.com/code/shivanimalhotra91/gensim-word2vec-lstm-95-accuracy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).