# error: RPC failed; curl 6 SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), err

Tags: python, git, heroku, flask, nltk

I'm trying to deploy flask app on heroku. Specifically, NLTK data to the server as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965823/resource-corpora-wordnet-not-found-on-heroku) solution. For some reason I keep getting this error. So I tried creating a new Heroku project and pushing my local project but still stuck with same error.

```
C:\Users\mysys\mywebservices-test\warm-sierra-60310>git push heroku mas
ter
Counting objects: 23005, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (22954/22954), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 6 SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), err
no 10053
The remote end hung up unexpectedly/23005), 499.96 MiB | 20.00 KiB/s
Writing objects: 100% (23005/23005), 1017.63 MiB | 1.88 MiB/s, done.
Total 23005 (delta 14999), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

This project works perfectly in my local machine.

```
C:\Users\mysys\mywebservices-test\warm-sierra-60310>python app.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2016 23:05:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2016 23:05:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Is there anything I could try? let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar problem with you, and finally it solved by the method below:

Look here: [Git push error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952683/git-push-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-200-fatal-the-remote-end-hun)

The problem is most likely caused by your low Git's buffer, which is not enough for your project.Maybe You can try to increase your Git’s HTTP buffer.

try this in git:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

This will increase your Git's buffer into 524288000.