# What does nltk.download("wordnet") accomplish

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, nltk

I wanted to know what `nltk.download()` do. Also, if I add "wordnet" as an argument, then what happens. Is `wordnet` like some dataset or something, I would like more clarification on that.

Comment: the simple answer to your question might be at the bottom of the documentation, http://www.nltk.org/install.html:  `After installing the NLTK package, please do install the necessary datasets/models for specific functions to work.

If you’re unsure of which datasets/models you’ll need, you can install the “popular” subset of NLTK data, on the command line type python -m nltk.downloader popular, or in the Python interpreter import nltk; nltk.download(‘popular’): 

For details, see http://www.nltk.org/data.html`

Comment: For downloading the specific "wordnet" dictionary in your example, this question may already be answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661108/import-wordnet-in-nltk, which suggests the method `nltk.download(<dictionary_name>)` , as the method name `download()` implies, instructs the nltk library to download the requested dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `nltk.download()` is not a file or module, but a resource id that maps to a corpus, machine-learning model or other resource (or collection of resources) to be installed in your NLTK_DATA area. You can see a list of the available resources, and their IDs, at http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/ .

You can use the special id "book" (as in `nltk.download("book")`) to download all resources mentioned in the nltk book; that's handy if you don't want to keep stopping your explorations to download missing resources.

Calling `nltk.dowload()` without an argument pops up an interactive browser window (if it can) that you can use to browse and select resources for download.